# html marquee alternate how to do?

Tags: html

```
<marquee behaviour="alternate" scrollamount="20" >SPORTS ROOM</marquee>
```

I'm using `marquee` code, I want my text move left to right and right to left.

How can I do this?

Comment: Once you implement this, please post a link for us to enjoy it.

Comment: The code you posted should achieve that already, unless the browser is refusing to honour the styling of the `marquee`.

Comment: Ah, the internet of 1996... sigh...

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with javascript. It looks like some working code was discussed in this forum post:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=151525

Or for a really simple jquery plugin check out:
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/
Demo'ed here: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

You might consider not using the marquee effect though -- its sorta scoffed at these days.